# Translate this jquery into coffee script?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm unsure how to structure the following. This works fine:

```
  $('.hover li').on 'hover', (ev) ->
    $(this).addClass('active')
```

I know I can use 'toggle' instead of 'addClass', but for other reasons I need a handler out function passed. So I tried this:

```
  $('.element').on 'hover', (ev)
    -> $(this).addClass('active'),
    -> $(this).removeClass('active')
```

This returns an error - 'unexpected ,'. I've tried other variations, and most of the examples I've found online do not use the `.on 'hover' (ev) ->` format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use `on()` for this if you'd like to attach both event handlers at a time.

You need to use `hover()`:

```
$('.element').hover(
  (ev) -> $(this).addClass 'active'
  (ev) -> $(this).removeClass 'active'
)
```

or even better, utilizing `toggleClass()`

```
$('.element').hover (ev) -> $(this).toggleClass 'active'
```

Comment: I did originally use toggleClass but if I were hovered over this element on page load, the element would start as active, then on hover, toggle to inactive and so on.

Comment: The syntax is correct, but the code did not work for me. The addClass/removeClass code is useless, and toggleClass has the error above mentioned by @DamienRoche (which is what I wanted to correct in my project).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's toggle function takes two functions, which I think is what you're after:

```
$('.element').toggle 'hover', 
    (ev) -> 
        $(this).addClass('active')
        # Do other stuff...
    (ev) -> 
        $(this).removeClass('active')
        # Do other stuff...
```

Answer (score -4):

```
$('.element').on 'hover', (ev) ->
  $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('active')
```

should do it. Although I don't get it. Your adding the class *active* and then removing it. Nevertheless, the above code is valid coffeescript at least.